# Thunderbird message filter misses messages when automatically run but works when manually run

Tags: thunderbird

I have defined several message filters. They are all `enabled` and each filter has the property `Getting new mail` and `Manually run` for "Apply filter when" set to active.

Sometimes some mails that should be filtered still land in the inbox. When I then run all filters manually on the inbox the filters are applied correctly.

How can it be that sometimes for some messages I have to run the filters manually when it should do it when getting the mail?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to be specific with regards to the filter and what it's doing, however try changing the filter to "filter before junk classification" or try after, depending on what's happening.

Comment: Is there a way of changing filters within the Thunderbird settings, as would allow search / replace of the setting you mentioned. Some of us have a large number of filters ...